# If it possible with jQuery onLoad function to load specific page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been wondering if this is possible, instead of building fully responsive website. I would like to build 2 different websites, 1 would be for phones (only small screens) and other for tablets and desktops.

Now in the mobile version of the website I would exclude large files and videos and so on.

I am wondering is something like this possible?

```
$(document).onLoad(function(){
    if(screen){
       \\ load mobile.html
    }else{ \\ load desktop.html }
});
```

Or maybe if there is a better way, I am mainly interested in completely excluding some elements from the DOM on mobile devices instead of only hiding them with CSS.

Thanks

Comment: responsive is the way to go these days, you will get better performance. it is possible.

Comment: And you don't worry about search engines indexing and ranking your pages?

Comment: ok but is it possible to exclude files completely on load? I know how to make it responsive but I don't know how to exclude files.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the document location. More about the location object [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp).

I wouldn't wait for the document to load as in your code, instead run it straight away.

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)").matches) {
  document.location.pathname = "desktop.html";
} else {
  document.location.pathname = "mobile.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As wnbates said, all you need to use is

```
document.location.pathname='url';
```

with your condition, with the condition using

```
window.matchMedia('(min-width: Npx)').matches
```

Keep in mind that you can use multiple if else conditions to match different widths. But then you may need to use `<`, `>`, `=` operators.